# Why isn't WSO2 ESB joining ELB cluster?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

We already have WSO2 ESB 4.6 in production so I'm using ESB 4.6.0 and ELB 2.0.3.

Following the instructions at https://docs.wso2.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=26839403 I seem to have successfully installed the ELB.  I tried setting up the ESB from scratch (as opposed to using our production instance or config) and started it up, but it isn't joining the cluster, and I'm unable to access the management console at https://mgt.esb.cloud-test.wso2.com:8243/carbon .  (In order to keep everything according to the installing instructions, I added elb.wso2.com, mgt.esb.cloud-test-wso2.com, and esb.cloud-test.wso2.com to /etc/hosts as . . .

```
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain elb.wso2.com mgt.esb.cloud-test.wso2.com esb.cloud-test.wso2.com
```

I haven't installed the ESB worker node yet, but that, the ESB management node, and the ELB will be on the same host for now.  I enabled the port offset for the management node.

I confirmed the hostnames and port numbers are correct in the ELB and ESB configurations.

This is the log from starting the ESB management node:

```
JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to /usr/java/jre1.7.0_17
CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to /opt/app/wso2esb-4.6.0-manager
[2014-12-09 13:37:13,474]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Starting WSO2 Carbon...
[2014-12-09 13:37:13,476]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Operating System : Linux 2.6.18-194.el5, amd64
[2014-12-09 13:37:13,476]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java Home        : /usr/java/jre1.7.0_17
[2014-12-09 13:37:13,476]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java Version     : 1.7.0_17
[2014-12-09 13:37:13,477]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java VM          : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 23.7-b01,Oracle Corporation
[2014-12-09 13:37:13,477]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Carbon Home      : /opt/app/wso2esb-4.6.0-manager
[2014-12-09 13:37:13,477]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java Temp Dir    : /opt/app/wso2esb-4.6.0-manager/tmp
[2014-12-09 13:37:13,477]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator User             : clowndrugs, en-US, America/Chicago
[2014-12-09 13:37:13,505]  WARN - ValidationResultPrinter Open files limit :1024 of the system is below the recommended minimum count :4096
[2014-12-09 13:37:13,522]  INFO - AgentHolder Agent created !
[2014-12-09 13:37:13,543]  INFO - AgentDS Successfully deployed Agent Client
[2014-12-09 13:37:16,158]  INFO - EmbeddedRegistryService Configured Registry in 40ms
[2014-12-09 13:37:16,260]  INFO - RegistryCoreServiceComponent Registry Mode    : READ-WRITE
[2014-12-09 13:37:17,612]  INFO - ClusterBuilder Clustering has been enabled
[2014-12-09 13:37:17,625]  INFO - ClusterBuilder Running in application mode
[2014-12-09 13:37:17,626]  INFO - ClusterBuilder Clustering configuration management has been enabled
[2014-12-09 13:37:17,627]  INFO - ClusterBuilder Clustering state management has been disabled
[2014-12-09 13:37:17,954]  INFO - LandingPageWebappDeployer Deployed product landing page webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/home]
[2014-12-09 13:37:18,049]  INFO - DeploymentInterceptor Deploying Axis2 service: echo {super-tenant}
[2014-12-09 13:37:18,237]  INFO - DeploymentEngine Deploying Web service: Echo.aar - file:/opt/app/wso2esb-4.6.0-manager/repository/deployment/server/axis2services/Echo.aar
[2014-12-09 13:37:18,324]  INFO - DeploymentInterceptor Deploying Axis2 service: Version {super-tenant}
[2014-12-09 13:37:18,344]  INFO - DeploymentEngine Deploying Web service: Version.aar - file:/opt/app/wso2esb-4.6.0-manager/repository/deployment/server/axis2services/Version.aar
[2014-12-09 13:37:18,607]  INFO - DeploymentInterceptor Deploying Axis2 service: echo {super-tenant}
[2014-12-09 13:37:18,700]  INFO - DeploymentInterceptor Deploying Axis2 service: Version {super-tenant}
[2014-12-09 13:37:18,795]  INFO - ModuleDeployer Deploying module: rampart-1.6.1-wso2v8 - file:/opt/app/wso2esb-4.6.0-manager/repository/deployment/client/modules/rampart-1.6.1-wso2v8.mar
[2014-12-09 13:37:18,798]  INFO - ModuleDeployer Deploying module: addressing-1.6.1-wso2v7 - file:/opt/app/wso2esb-4.6.0-manager/repository/deployment/client/modules/addressing-1.6.1-wso2v7.mar
[2014-12-09 13:37:18,803]  INFO - TCPTransportSender TCP Sender started
[2014-12-09 13:37:19,992]  INFO - DeploymentEngine Deploying Web service: org.wso2.carbon.message.processor -
[2014-12-09 13:37:20,000]  INFO - DeploymentEngine Deploying Web service: org.wso2.carbon.message.store -
[2014-12-09 13:37:21,806]  INFO - DeploymentInterceptor Deploying Axis2 service: wso2carbon-sts {super-tenant}
[2014-12-09 13:37:21,959]  INFO - DeploymentEngine Deploying Web service: org.wso2.carbon.sts -
[2014-12-09 13:37:22,205]  INFO - DeploymentEngine Deploying Web service: org.wso2.carbon.tryit -
[2014-12-09 13:37:22,497]  INFO - CarbonServerManager Repository       : /opt/app/wso2esb-4.6.0-manager/repository/deployment/server/
[2014-12-09 13:37:22,743]  INFO - PermissionUpdater Permission cache updated for tenant -1234
[2014-12-09 13:37:22,815]  INFO - ServiceBusInitializer Starting ESB...
[2014-12-09 13:37:22,832]  INFO - ServiceBusInitializer Initializing Apache Synapse...
[2014-12-09 13:37:22,836]  INFO - SynapseControllerFactory Using Synapse home : /opt/app/wso2esb-4.6.0-manager/.
[2014-12-09 13:37:22,836]  INFO - SynapseControllerFactory Using synapse.xml location : /opt/app/wso2esb-4.6.0-manager/././repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default
[2014-12-09 13:37:22,836]  INFO - SynapseControllerFactory Using server name : localhost
[2014-12-09 13:37:22,839]  INFO - SynapseControllerFactory The timeout handler will run every : 15s
[2014-12-09 13:37:22,845]  INFO - Axis2SynapseController Initializing Synapse at : Tue Dec 09 13:37:22 CST 2014
[2014-12-09 13:37:22,845]  INFO - Axis2SynapseController Loading mediator extensions...
[2014-12-09 13:37:22,848]  INFO - CarbonSynapseController Loading the mediation configuration from the file system
[2014-12-09 13:37:22,850]  INFO - MultiXMLConfigurationBuilder Building synapse configuration from the synapse artifact repository at : ././repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default
[2014-12-09 13:37:22,850]  INFO - XMLConfigurationBuilder Generating the Synapse configuration model by parsing the XML configuration
[2014-12-09 13:37:23,075]  INFO - SynapseConfigurationBuilder Loaded Synapse configuration from the artifact repository at : ././repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default
[2014-12-09 13:37:23,076]  INFO - Axis2SynapseController Deploying the Synapse service...
[2014-12-09 13:37:23,078]  INFO - Axis2SynapseController Deploying Proxy services...
[2014-12-09 13:37:23,078]  INFO - Axis2SynapseController Deploying EventSources...
[2014-12-09 13:37:23,083]  INFO - ServerManager Server ready for processing...
[2014-12-09 13:37:23,120]  WARN - MediationStatisticsComponent Can't register an observer for mediationStatisticsStore. If you have disabled StatisticsReporter, please enable it in the Carbon.xml
[2014-12-09 13:37:23,177]  INFO - RuleEngineConfigDS Successfully registered the Rule Config service
[2014-12-09 13:37:24,407]  INFO - HttpsTransportListener HTTPS port       : 9444
[2014-12-09 13:37:24,407]  INFO - HttpTransportListener HTTP port        : 9764
[2014-12-09 13:37:24,408]  INFO - TribesClusteringAgent Initializing cluster...
[2014-12-09 13:37:24,423]  INFO - TribesClusteringAgent Cluster domain: wso2.esb.domain
[2014-12-09 13:37:24,425]  INFO - TribesClusteringAgent Using wka based membership management scheme
[2014-12-09 13:37:24,433]  INFO - WkaBasedMembershipScheme Receiver Server Socket bound to:/10.221.90.92:4001
[2014-12-09 13:37:24,535]  INFO - WkaBasedMembershipScheme Receiver Server Socket bound to:/10.221.90.92:4001
[2014-12-09 13:37:24,639]  INFO - WkaBasedMembershipScheme Could not connect to member 127.0.0.1:4000(wso2.esb.domain)
[2014-12-09 13:37:24,653]  INFO - TribesClusteringAgent Local Member 10.221.90.92:4001(wso2.esb.domain)
[2014-12-09 13:37:24,653]  INFO - TribesUtil No members in current cluster
[2014-12-09 13:37:24,654]  INFO - TribesClusteringAgent Cluster initialization completed.
[2014-12-09 13:37:25,828]  INFO - RegistryEventingServiceComponent Successfully Initialized Eventing on Registry
[2014-12-09 13:37:25,943]  INFO - JMXServerManager JMX Service URL  : service:jmx:rmi://localhost:11112/jndi/rmi://localhost:10000/jmxrmi
[2014-12-09 13:37:25,943]  INFO - StartupFinalizerServiceComponent Server           :  WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus-4.6.0
[2014-12-09 13:37:25,944]  INFO - StartupFinalizerServiceComponent WSO2 Carbon started in 17 sec
[2014-12-09 13:37:26,567]  INFO - CarbonUIServiceComponent Mgt Console URL  : https://mgt.esb.cloud-test.wso2.com:8243/carbon/
```

The output from the ELB gives lots of these:

```
[2014-12-09 15:33:44,773] ERROR - TenantAwareLoadBalanceEndpoint No application members available
```

Is this expected behavior since I have yet set up any services or a worker node?  From the instructions, it sounded like I should be able to see the management node's Web console at this point.

Answer (score 0):

try the following changes and see

1. modify elb.wso2.com in ELB axis2.xml file
2. modify mgt.esb.cloud-test-wso2.com in ESB axis2.xml file